# Создание массива делегатов из массива MethodInfo[]

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Хай!
Получаю все нужные методы

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Есть словарь, `Dictionary<string, Action<MethodParam>> methods;`
Т.е. метод должен получить экземпляр типа `MethodParam`.
Как `MethodInfo` добавть в этот словарь?
Т.е.

```
foreach (var item in methodInfos)
    {
        methods.Add(item.Name.ToLower(), x => Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<MethodParam>), x, item));
    }
```

Что-то типа этого.

Спасибо!

Comment: а какие методы пытаются преобразовать к этому типу делегата?

Comment: @Grundy
Например:      




    `public void SetRoomLight(MethodParam methodParam)
  
  {
                rooms[methodParam.roomIndex].SetLightMode(Room.LightMode.Manual);
        rooms[methodParam.roomIndex].SetLightIntensity(methodParam.lightIntensity);
   
 }`


Вот такая сигнатура.

Comment: то есть все полученные метод в массиве methodInfos соответствуют сигнатуре? или все-таки не все?

Comment: Да, все. Но проблема уже решена, спасибо.

Comment: Еще немного про Delegate.CreateDelegate: [Связанный с делегатом объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674944/186999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если методы все с одинаковой сигнатурой, подойдёт такое:

```
var dict = methodInfos.ToDictionary(
    mi => mi.Name.ToLowerInvariant(),
    mi => (Action<MethodParam>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
              typeof(Action<MethodParam>), this, mi));
```

Comment: да, спасибо, все работает. Видимо я в аргументах метода CreateDelegate() запутался.

Comment: @the_anonymous: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @the_anonymous если ваш вопрос решен, то отметьте ответ как принятый.